# Type inference in Typescript callback with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a class that has a callback as one of its attributes. This callback uses a generic class:

```js
export class ColumnDefinition {
  public afterDialogClosedCallback: <T extends Row>(row: T, columnDefinition: string) => void;
}
```

I also have a builder that sets this property:

```js
export class ColumnDefinitionBuilder {
  private readonly instance: ColumnDefinition;

  private constructor() {
    this.instance = new ColumnDefinition();
  }

 public setAfterDialogClosedCallback(afterDialogClosedCallback: <T extends Row>(row: T, columnIdentifier: string) => void): ColumnDefinitionBuilder {
    this.instance.afterDialogClosedCallback = afterDialogClosedCallback;
    return this;
  }

}
```

The problem comes when I call the setter with a callback that receives a child of class Row as one of its arguments:

Class ProductRow is a child of Row:

```js
export class ProductRow extends Row {

}
```

and method notifyCellChanged receives an object of its type as the argument:

```js
  public override notifyCellChanged(row: ProductRow, columnIdentifier: string): void {

}
```

But when I try to pass this method as an argument to setAfterDialogClosedCallback:

```js
.setAfterDialogClosedCallback(this.notifyCellChanged)
```

I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '(row: ProductRow, columnIdentifier: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '<T extends Row>(row: T, columnIdentifier: string) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'row' and 'row' are incompatible.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ProductRow'.
      Type 'Row' is missing the following properties from type 'ProductRow'
```